# How can we edit a Program Stage Instance that is not marked as completed but DHIS2 doesn't allow to edit it?

Tags: dhis2

While being superuser of my DHIS2 Instance, sometimes my users (or even myself) try to edit a Program Stage Instance that is **not** marked as completed but the editing of the elements seems disabled (even after checking that the status is not completed).
Clearing browser cache and/or refreshing the page does not help.
Sometimes, it becomes available to be edited by itself the next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we were trying to edit that program instance while not selecting the proper org unit on the left panel.
As soon as the proper org unit on the left panel is selected and the program instance selected and incompleted we were able to edit it.
Thank you for your help.
P.S: the solution came through the email thread but thought to mention it here.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you could add DHIS2 version and build date. The below answer is general, as there are slight variations in the different versions of DHIS2.

There are three main reasons why a program stage instance(event) is  locked:

- The event was completed, and the program stage is configured to lock data entry after completion.
- The program stage uses a period(monthly for example), and the month of the event is expired.
- The event belongs to another organisation unit than the one the user currently reports for. If you are working on developing and testing a program this is often the reason why you would not be able to edit events, and do not have functionality to incomplete them. Even as administrator(ALL) you will have to select the same organisation unit that the event was originally captured for before opening the tracked entity instance dashboard.

Comment: Thank you Markus!
In fact i'm using 2.28 build 20aad4a 2018-04-24 06:22
and as a super user and root user, i have access to incomplete that instance and so i did incomplete it but still can't edit it.
The program stage we are using does not use period. and the event belongs to an org unit that i am in (in addition to the fact that i am super user and have access to all rights and org units)
The challenge is even if the instance is not complete, i can not edit that instance.

Comment: is there any other reason which renders that instance not editable? maybe because another user is accessing that instance?